# missing System.Web.Security in project

Tags: security, authentication, .net-core, model-view-controller

I am working on a web  project with *.Net core 3.1*.
I need to use   *FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie* in login action and when i add ***using System.Web.Security*** to project its unknown. I cant add this using.
I read all posts about but still wasn't able to solve this.

Comment: `System.Web` -> ASP.NET -> **not** available in ASP.NET Core -> nothing you can do about it, except, of course, use another authentication system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied many references and finally the result was nothing else this :
System.Web.Security only is available with .net framework  and in core has no alternative or i couldn't find it.